# Why the transform never rotate between the range angle of 70 and -70?

Tags: unity, c#

When running the game the rotationRange is always 0.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotateturret : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum RotateOnAxis { rotateOnX, rotateOnY, rotateOnZ };
    public bool randomRotation = false;
    [Range(0, 360)]
    public int rotationRange = 70;

    private void Start()
    {

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (randomRotation == true)
        {
            rotationRange = Random.Range(rotationRange, -rotationRange);
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.right, rotationRange);
        }
    }
}
```

I want it to rotate on the x axis between 70 and -70

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to flip the parameters, [`Random.Range`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) wants the min value first, max second.

So `rotationRange = Random.Range(-rotationRange, rotationRange);`.

Also, are you sure that you want to reassign to `rotationRange`? That way negative numbers (or zero) will mess up your system on future iterations.

Comment: Right assign it to the same variable rotationRange is a mistake. Using a local variable make it works. var rr = Random.Range(-rotationRange, rotationRange);
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.right, rr);  Thanks.